Building docker images in K8S pod
I would like to run a CI/CD (lets say selfhosted github runners) inside kubernetes
some workflows require to build docker images
but apparently you cannot just mount /var/run/docker.sock to k8s pod - as newer versions of k8s do not have it(?)
what's the solution to simply building images (not running - only building Dockerfile and push to registry)

Not sure if it is the (most) recommended way, but you can build images with a kaniko image/pod as described here by Gitlab…

You can use buildah or podman to build images, neither of which requires a running Docker daemon.

You can use Docker in Docker (DIND) building method. Kaniko is one of the tools which will do it

Kaniko is explicity not DIND.  The whole point of OP's question is that DIND does not work with recent releases of k8s, due to dockershim being deprecated

Kaniko is not building using docker, but it is a tool that can be used to build conatiner images in a kubernetes cluster.
@SiHa

Thanks, Shmuel! It’s my mistake. Will dive a little bit deeper into it
